# Cordova angularjs window.alert() calls on iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I have two consecutive calls to window.alert() in my angularjs code,
running on iOS through Cordova.
It's doing the most peculiar thing, running the second, then going back
to the previous one. Does anyone have any clue about this behavior?

Comment: Is this specific to cordova or do you experience it on other platforms as well?  Are the two calls to window.alert() happening within the same method synchronously or are they perhaps occurring as a result of separate watches?  Given that window.alert() is native browser code and not actually angular code, what makes you suspect this is related to angularjs specifically?

Comment: They aren't being called through any watches, they are just being called inside a view model defined method (called by ng-click on some button). As far as I could see, consecutive window.alert() calls are being executed one-by-one on different platforms